# Не работает auto-fill в Grid

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid

Не работает свойство:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
```

Просмотрел весь Google, ничего по этой теме нет.

Нашел только такую же проблему на [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478986/using-auto-fill-value-in-repeat-function-doesnt-work-in-firefox), но и это не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В названии свойства букву **n** потеряли: `grid-template-columns`

Comment: Ошибка не в букве!(

Comment: @DmitryFilippov Я вашу проблему никак не вопроизведу. К примеру, вот рабочий [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psn941qm/). Что значит формулировка "не работает"? Свойство корректно воспринимается Chrome и Firefox.